# How to remove NUL strings at begining of CSV; VBA

Tags: vba, csv, filesystemobject

I have a program that exports a bill of material (see CSV example data lower in post).

I wrote a VBA macro that uses FileSystemObject to loop through a user-selected folder, open the CSV files for reading and read the data into memory using ReadAll, then store and sort the data in excel.

The problem I have is after exporting the CSV files, I run the macro and the text in the CSV file is stored in my string variable (sTemp in the code below) as several square braces. I copied the value of the string variable and pasted it in a text editor and it appears as several repeating black boxes containing "SOH". Because the data is read incorrectly, the macro fails downstream.

If I open the original CSV file, the first two characters are black boxes that say "NUL".
NUL NUL "Pattern","Qty","Size","Material","Description","Length (ft)"
2041,,"3","","316L Stainless Sch 10S PE",20
2041,,"3","","316L Stainless Sch 10S PE",2.21
5044,1,"3","Stainless Steel: 304L","DET S10 SS BUTT WELD",
2523,1,"3","Stainless Steel: 316L","316L-SS-SCH10 Short Radius 90",
2522,1,"3","Stainless Steel: 304L","DET S10 SS BUTT WELD",

If I save the CSV files in Excel close them, the two "NUL" characters are gone:
"Pattern","Qty","Size","Material","Description","Length (ft)"
2041,,"3","","316L Stainless Sch 10S PE",20
2041,,"3","","316L Stainless Sch 10S PE",2.21
5044,1,"3","Stainless Steel: 304L","DET S10 SS BUTT WELD",
2523,1,"3","Stainless Steel: 316L","316L-SS-SCH10 Short Radius 90",
2522,1,"3","Stainless Steel: 304L","DET S10 SS BUTT WELD",

After running the macro on the saved files, the string variable (sTemp in the code below) contains the proper text in the CSV file.

I would like to know how to eliminate the NUL strings in the beginning of the CSV and would like to avoid opening and saving the CSV files programmatically if at all possible.

```
'Variables for accessing and cleaning text files
Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject 'File System Object grants access to computer files and folders
Dim sSourceFolder As String 'Path of oSourceFolder
Dim oSourceFolder 'Folder the original CSV file is stored in
Dim oFile 'The orignal CSV
Dim sFileToCopy As String 'Path of the copied CSV
Dim sTargetFolder As String 'The path of oTargetFolder
Dim oTargetFolder 'The folder the new CSV file is stored in
Dim oCopiedText 'The copied text file
Dim oCopiedFile 'The copied file itself
Dim oInput 'Represents the text in the CSV ror readin in CSV to memory
Dim sTemp As String 'For storing CSV data in memory
Dim cFiles As New Collection 'Storage for all the files in all the sub folders
Dim sPath As String 'The path of one of the files, will be reused for each file

'variables for progress
Dim iFiles As Integer
Dim Progress As Double

'Constants for reading and writing to text files
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

'File System Object grants access to computer files and folders
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Select the folder to get CSV files from
sSourceFolder = GetFolder("C:\", "Select Folder Containing CSV files")
Set oSourceFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sSourceFolder) 'Tell File System Object to get a hold of oSourceFolder so you can look into it

'Check/create the _Cleaned folder inside of the source folder
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
sTargetFolder = oSourceFolder.Path & "\" & oSourceFolder.Name & "_Cleaned"
Set oTargetFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sTargetFolder)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'create the folder
    oTargetFolder = oFSO.CreateFolder(sTargetFolder)
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Loop through and clean each CSV so it can be opened in excel properly
iFiles = oSourceFolder.Files.Count
Progress = 0

For Each oFile In oSourceFolder.Files 'go through each file
    Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & Progress & " of " & CStr(iFiles) & ": " & Format(Progress / iFiles, "0%")
    If Right(oFile, 3) = "csv" Then   'if it is a text file...
        'Copy the original file path
        sFileToCopy = oFile.Path

        'Open txt file in memory
        Set oInput = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFileToCopy, ForReading)

        'Input txt from file to memory
        sTemp = oInput.ReadAll
        'sTemp contains a repeating SOH string if I do not save the files first and the macro fails downstream
        'If I open the CSV file in excel, save it, close it, then run the macro, sTemp contains the string data in the file and the macro runs fine
```

'Can I somehow delete the NUL strings at this point?
            .
            .
            .

I expect the sTemp value to read the actual text in the CSV file:
"Pattern,Qty,Size,Material,Description,Length (ft)
2041,,3,,316L Stainless Sch 10S PE,20"

Instead the sTemp value in the VBA locals window is:
"[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[["
And when I copy the value and paste it into a text editor it reads:
"1
SOH SOH SOH SOH SOH SOH"

Files are saved here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e8ohn61bxqidejd/AAB9CMno8N_EXdlA83TBX602a?dl=0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing a sample of the original csv file it's highly unlikely that anyone will be able to help with this

Comment: I don’t have credentials to upload pics and didn’t see how to upload the files. I added snippets of the files in the post and noticed the NUL strings at the beginning of the original files.

Comment: I suspect file encoding,  or format, so likely only the actual file will do.  The extra characters you mention tend to confirm this.  Perhaps the real issue is in how the files are generated.  You could upload to a file sharing site and share the link.  FYI, it's never a good idea to post _only_ an image of data (or code)

Comment: I will look into the file sharing site. I was only suggesting the image as a work around to my lacking credentials.

Comment: Added files to Dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indead do have a file with the first two characters as ASCI 0.

Is see two main options:

1. Fix the export that created these files to not generate the NULL's, or
2. Strip the leading NULL characters.

For option2, it seems ReadAll fails, but ReadLine works.

Demo of   stripping the NULLs

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim oInput As TextStream
    Dim sTemp

    Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set oInput = oFSO.OpenTextFile("Your\File.csv")
    sTemp = oInput.ReadLine
    Do While Left$(sTemp, 1) = Chr(0)
        sTemp = Mid$(sTemp, 2)
    Loop
    Do Until oInput.AtEndOfStream
        sTemp = sTemp & vbCrLf & oInput.ReadLine
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this a try and let you know how it works out.

Comment: This solution is excellent! Works great! Thanks for the help. I had no idea they were Chr(0) characters (I see them in the ASCII table now though http://www.asciitable.com/). Slick how you strip them off as you read the line. Many thanks!