# How to merge/import new data into Excel sheet with multiple matching columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have monthly CSV files supplied from another program that I need to import into Excel and analyse the data to provide monthly and year to date reports.

The difficulty I am having is twofold. The report columns do not align month to month and the program that generates them repeats column names for matching data.

File 1:
**Title | Label | Label | Label | Date       | ....**
Stuff | Mice  | Cats  | Dogs  | 01/01/2020 | ....

File 2:
**Title | Label | Label | Date       | ....**
Stuff | Birds  | Fish   | 02/02/2020 | ....

As you can see month 2, there was 1 less label and therefore one less column, however if i concatenate them into 1 field then how do I analyse the number of each label used per month?

I have tried to import them as queries from CSV, and adding to the data model then making a pivot table, but there are approx 100 columns each month and then excel bugs out and runs out of memory.

Ideally I would end up with a table/graph that shows (and allows me to import each month without needing to format tables:

```
Label | Jan | Feb | and so on ...
Mice  | 7   | 0   |
Cats  | 1   | 2   |
Dogs  | 0   | 5   |
Fish  | 3   | 92  |
```

and so on.........

Comment: I'd open the file as text, and parse the data to suit your purposes.  [Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54623925/445425)

Comment: If you want to benefit from using Pivot Tables, best way would be having a data source of just 4 fields: Title, Label, Quantity, Date. So line 1 would be something like Stuff, Mice, 7, 01/01/2020, line 2 Stuff, Cats, 1, 01/01/202 and so on. Then your Pivot Table would work perfectly to get the desired output. The big issue here is about rearrange data to fit that model. Probably you would need a macro in VBA to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i figured it out.
Rather than trying to import it and it stuff up (encapsulated comma's aplenty) I decided to open in the background and copy worksheet into current workbook.

Like this....

```
Sub IMPORT_MONTH()

    Dim fileName As Variant

    'open dialogue box to get new file to import
    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
            
    If fileName = False Then
        MsgBox ("Why did you click cancel?")
        Exit Sub
    End If
            
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    ' run update in background
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
    closedBook.Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'move cursor to home for ease of readability
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox ("It Broke")

End Sub
```